# Que significa "tirar o coelho da cartola"?

Tags: significado, expressões, uso-de-palavras

O que significa a expressão "tirar o coelho da cartola"?

Em que contexto ela pode ser empregada?

Comment: Ander, tinhas um "1. list item" na tua pergunta, que eu tirei . Não sei se era um exemplo que pensaste incluir, e depois não correu bem... De qualquer modo, clicando em "edit" no canto inferior esquerdo, podes modificar a pergunta à tua vontade.

Answer (score 5):

Significa uma ação inesperada e improvável, especialmente numa situação de desvantagem. A expressão é muitas vezes utilizado por comentaristas de futebol com o sentido de apresentar uma recuperação abrupta num jogo ou torneio até então fraco - nesse sentido poderia ser substituída por "se superar". Por [exemplo](https://www.msn.com/es-us/noticias/estados-unidos/pvc-tim%C3%A3o-precisa-tirar-coelho-da-cartola/vp-BBOuj69):

> Timão precisa tirar 'coelho da cartola'
>
> Comentarista acredita que o time alvinegro precisa se superar para quebrar o setor defensivo cruzeirense

A origem do termo é o [tradicional truque](https://incrivel.club/admiracao-curiosidades/5-truques-de-magica-revelados-64305/) de shows de mágica, de se retirar um coelho de uma cartola antes vazia.

Answer (score 1):

Tirar um coelho da cartola é o mesmo que surpreender em algum momento complicado ou difícil. Seria como fazer uma mágica para superar algo.

Comment: A última frase resume muito bem o termo.